# get JSON object from knockout observable array by objects id

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, knockout.js

I can't find anything but basic examples of ko.observablearrays that show arrays of simple strings. I have an observable array that holds a largish JSON object with a lot of properties. I need to get the one of the objects in the array based off on the id property in the array. I have this code to get the Id:

```
self.selectedOrgId.subscribe(function (currentOrgId) {
    alert(currentOrgId);
}, self);
```

my observable array is populated via an ajax get request and looks something like this:

```
[
{"userGuid":"37ab100e-f97b-462a-b3f4-79b8fbe24831",
"orgId":1,
"orgName":
"company ltd",
"isHiring":true,
...snip...}
   more...
]
```

How can I look into my array and get the object with the orgId that I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to find a specific object based on its id you can use `ko.utils.arrayFirst` as follow :

```
var selectemItemID = '1';
var selectemItem = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.items(), function(i) {
    return i.orgId == selectemItemID;
});
```

But you can also create an computed property that returns the selected item based on the selected item id.

```
self.selectedItem = ko.computed({
    read : function(){
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.items(), function(i) {
            return this.selectedOrgId() == i.orgId;
        });
   },
   owner : self
});
```